# Javascript: how to check empty object in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting an array of objects from my JSON response. Sometimes I am getting an array of length 1 with an empty object. How do I check that condition?

```
I tried with a few things-

  myarray[0]=='empty' || myarray[0] == 'undefined'
  or myarray.indexOf(0)== -1
```

But didn't solved the problem

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? The most "empty" value I can think of is `undefined`, but JSON can't give you an array with an `undefined` entry, as it doesn't have that concept.

Comment: FYI, `myarray[0]=='empty'` tests whether the first array element is the **string** `'empty'`. That doesn't seem like a useful thing to try in the first place. Similarly, `myarray.indexOf(0)` tries to find the index of the *value* `0`. It seems you nee to ramp up on some JavaScript basics about values: http://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html, http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html .

Answer (score 21):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to return all property names and check it's length:

```
Object.keys(myarray[0]).length === 0;
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I get the impression it's something like `"[{}]"`.  Question could be clarified somewhat.

Comment: I misunderstood your answer. You may well be right about what the user means, nice catch.

Comment: Need to add `&& myarray.length == 1` to exactly match the requirements, but I think this is what the OP wants

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what you mean by "empty."

### If you mean an object with no properties

If you mean you're getting:

```
 [{}]
```

...then [madox2's answer is a good way to check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36206270/157247). Alternatively, you might have a function to do it that you can reuse:

```
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        if (Object.hasOwn(obj, key)) { // Remove this if you want to check for
                                       // enumerable inherited properties
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

(`Object.hasOwn` was added in ES2022, but is easily polyfilled.)

### If you mean `[null]` or similar

If you want to check specifically for `undefined` (note the `===` rather than `==`) (but you won't get `undefined` from JSON):

```
if (myarray[0] === undefined)
```

Or specifically for `null` (note the `===` rather than `==`):

```
if (myarray[0] === null)
```

Or for either of those (note the `==` rather than `===`):

```
if (myarray[0] == null)
```

Or for any *falsy* value (`0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, or of course, `false`):

```
if (!myarray[0])
```